# Call javascript function from iOS App?

Tags: javascript, ios

I have an ios app built from gonative.io (essentially they use a webview to load in the app a website content). I'm trying to call a javascript function to set username and password (or set them directly from the ios oproject) if the user already logged in. Anyone know how can I do that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: refer to this post [execute javascript in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26778955/6521116) and [javascript in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41488423/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WKWebview's **[evaluateJavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript)**. You also can refer [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43628398/6521116).

```
self.wk.evaluateJavaScript("var rect = document.getElementById('movie').getBoundingClientRect(); [rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left];") { (result, error) -> Void in
        print(result)
}
```